# Prevent inadvertent replacement in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace

Is there a way to make Notepad++ to ask for confirmation when replacing all instances of a string in a file or files?

This is to prevent inadvertent replacement.

Comment: Can't you just replace one by one instead of doing replace all?

Comment: Sublime Text 2 asks for a confirmation when replacing multiple instances. Besides, Sublime Text 2 is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. If you're modifying a single file, I don't think it's needed.

Clicking **Replace All** always displays a dialog showing how many occurrences were replaced. To revert the changes, just give focus to the text window and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to undo the last operation.

Comment: Would this undo all changes in all the files changed?

Comment: I think it would apply to each instance a repacement was performed.  52 replacements? Then you would need to ctrl+z 52 times, or, just hold the two keys down for a few seconds and let the keyboard do the repeating for you.. (this takes a little skill)>

Comment: So, this means if the string was replaced in 30 files, and say 10 times in each files then one has to do what?:(

Comment: @mpajoh: I don't have Windows installed right now, so I can't confirm if you can undo edits in all files simultaneously, but you only have to press the key combination *once* to undo all replaces in one file.

Comment: @mpajoh just try it yourself... It undoes all replacements in one file for sure, but I've never used "replace in all open files" so I don't know if ctrl+z also undoes in all files.

Comment: @Luc On the "Find In Files" tab with a *.* as the file filter and a directory specified, NPP will replace all instances of the string in all the files of the that directory, not just open files, right?  This is why I think in these situation a "Are you sure" dialog box may be a good idea.

Comment: @mpajoh Oh that feature, hmm think I used that once, and also think it warned me that it might give irreversible results. Not on Windows though; can't try either. Why don't you?

Comment: @Luc No thanks. I have tried this once, and that is all it takes:(,  and no it does not warn or ask for confirmation of any kind that I remember, otherwise I would have stopped it.  This may be a feature to request.  Does anyone have an idea where this can be requested?

Comment: @mpajoh At the notepadplusplus.org website there are links to Google+, Twitter and Facebook on every page. And also: http://notepad-plus-plus.org/contributors/author.html http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/forums This should be enough to get in touch.